# How to Graph Floor/Ceiling Functions in LaTeX (PGFPlots)

Tags: graphics, pgfplots

I am trying to make a graph of some floor/ceiling functions for examplep the floor of 3x+2 like this: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+floor%283x%2B2%29#*=*.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20of%20floor%283x%2b2%29#_=_)

However, I searched through the PFGPlots manual and did not find a mention of that. Does anyone know how to do this in LaTeX or PGFplots?

Comment: The PGFmath package includes a `ceil` and a `floor` function. The `pgfplots` offers a few options for Constant Plots (see manual v1.8, subsection 4.4.3, pp. 57ff.). The option `jump mark left` for example might help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `jump mark mid` style for this, which draws horizontal unconnected line segments.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    domain=-3:3,
    samples=100,
    very thick, red
] {floor(3*x)+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to get

[image]

---

A fancier approach could be to use the `discontinuous` style from the question [Probability density function of Uniform Distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117954/probability-density-function-of-uniform-distribution) to plot the intervals.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I have two questions, is Ceil the function for Ceiling? So Ceil(3*x+2) because it does not work for me. Also, when I try to graph the fancy one twice (2 graphs) it connects the 2nd graph with the 1st graph by a dotted line?

Comment: And if I wanted to make the title of the graph the function, where should the title = {} code go?

Comment: @Goose: The `ceil` function isn't defined in PGFPlots by default, but you can easily define it yourself (I've edited my answer). Sorry about the connecting line, that was an oversight on my part. It's fixed now. The `title=<text>` code goes in the `axis` options, so you'd say `\begin{axis}[title=My title, axis lines=middle]`.

Comment: Wow I wish I could upvote your answer twice! My last question is can I embed functions like this: {Floor(2{Ceil(x/2)}+.5)}? To produce [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+floor%282%28ceiling%28x%2F2%29%29%2B.5%29)

Comment: @Goose: Sure: `\addplot [
 domain=-3:3,
 samples=121,
 jump mark mid,
 discontinuous,
 very thick, blue
] {Floor(2*(Ceil(x/2))+.5)};`

Comment: The MWE as provided works great. However, if I plot `Floor(x)` instead of `Floor(3*x+2)`, the point at x=0 seems shifted to the right for some reason. The other discontinuities are fine, just the one at x=0 has an issue.

Comment: Also, there should not be a filled circle at the start of the domain (unless it is an integer).  [Here](http://imgur.com/QNHZc77) is the image showing both issues.

Comment: Sorry, am I missing something? `ceil(1.0)` should be `1.0`, but `round(1.0 + 0.5)` is `round(1.5)` which is `2.0`.

Comment: @wchargin: Good catch! By now, correct `ceil` and `floor` functions [have been added](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex?r1=1.1&r2=1.2) to the FPU library, so I've removed the wrong definition from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two small refinements to Jake's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118409/16967):

- The start and end line have only half of the line width as the
  other lines because of `pgfplot`'s clipping of the plot area.
  This can be fixed by either disable clipping `clip=false` or
  enlarging the plot are in the vertical directions: `enlarge y limits={abs=.6pt}` (`very thick` is 1.2pt).
- The more serious issue is that the start and end points of the lines
  are not correct, after adding option `grid`:

  > [image: viewport]

  The sample points left and right of a jump value do not have the same distance, for example at x = 1.

There are two ways of fixing it:

The first way works by accident only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, grid, clip=false]
\addplot [
    jump mark right,
    mark=*,
    domain=-3:3,
    samples=19,
    very thick, red
] {floor(3*x)+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The sample points are marked. The number of samples is the number of lines plus one for an additional end point:

> [image: Result]

It works only, because x values for the sample points except the first are
a tiny bit (rounding error) too small.

A more stable solution is to use the middle points of the lines. Unhappily it complicates the domain and plot area options.
Version with grid and marked sample points and without clipping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    grid,
    clip=false,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    ymin=-7,
    ymax=10,
    enlarge y limits={abs=.6pt}, % very thick: 1.2pt
]
\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    mark=*,
    domain=-3 - 1/6:3 + 1/6,
    samples=20,
    very thick, red
] {floor(3*x)+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with debug info]

And the final solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    ymin=-7,
    ymax=10,
    enlarge y limits={abs=.6pt}, % very thick: 1.2pt
]
\addplot [
    jump mark mid,
    domain=-3 - 1/6:3 + 1/6,
    samples=20,
    very thick, red
] {floor(3*x)+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Final result]